# Erlang: spawn a process and wait for termination without using `receive`

Tags: erlang

In Erlang, can I call some function `f` (BIF or not), whose job is to spawn a process, run the function `argf` I provided, and doesn't "return" until `argf` has "returned", and do this without using `receive` clause (the reason for this is that `f` will be invoked in a gen_server, I don't want pollute the gen_server's mailbox).

A snippet would look like this:

```
%% some code omitted ...
F = fun() -> blah, blah, timer:sleep(10000) end,
f(F), %% like `spawn(F), but doesn't return until 10 seconds has passed`
%% ...
```

Comment: What do you need this for? why not just run this `fun()` from the main process?

Comment: @A.Sarid broadcast to many clients parallelly, (say spawn 5 processes, each handles `nbr_clients/5` clients)

Comment: Well I don't think you need to be worried from using `trap_exit` and `receive` block. Message passing is one of the main things in Erlang. You won't "pollute" the mailbox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will not "pollute" the gen_servers mailbox if you spawn+wait for message before you return from the call or cast. A more serious problem with this maybe that you will block the gen_server while you are waiting for the other process to terminate. A way around this is to not explicitly wait but return from the call/cast and then when the completion message arrives handle it in `handle_info/2` and then do what is necessary.

If the spawning is done in a `handle_call` and you want to return the "result" of that process then you can delay returning the value to the original call from the `handle_info` handling the process termination message.

Note that however you do it a `gen_server:call` has a timeout value, either implicit or explicit, and if no reply is returned it generates an error in the calling process.

Comment: I end up using `receive` clause, created a function like `pmap`, (except that it doesn't collect result, just wait for termination). As for the blocking, as long as it doesn't block the calling process from receiving messages, it's probably ok - I don't want to process next request until this one is processed anyway. I considered your alternative approach as well, the drawback is that it would introduce state (ok_to_accept_new_request or waiting_the_current_job to_be_done) between handle_cast (I'm using cast to communicate), and I also have to deal with timeouts, seems not worth the trouble.

Answer (score 2):

The only way to communicate between processes is message passing (of course you can consider to poll for a specific key in an ets or a file but I dont like this).

If you use a spawn_monitor function in f/1 to start the F process and then have a receive block only matching the possible system messages from this monitor:

```
f(F) ->
    {_Pid, MonitorRef} = spawn_monitor(F),    
    receive
        {_Tag, MonitorRef, _Type, _Object, _Info} -> ok
    end.
```

you will not mess your gen_server mailbox. The example is the minimum code, you can add a timeout (fixed or parameter), execute some code on normal or error completion...

Comment: Guess you are right about the only way to communicate between processes, maybe I'm doing this the wrong way.

Answer (score 1):

Main way to communicate with process in Erlang VM space is message passing with [`erlang:send/2`](http://erlang.org/doc/man/erlang.html#send-2) or [`erlang:send/3`](http://erlang.org/doc/man/erlang.html#send-3) functions (alias `!`). But you can "hack" Erlang and use multiple way for communicating over process.

You can use [`erlang:link/1`](http://erlang.org/doc/man/erlang.html#link-1) to communicate stat of the process, its mainly used in case of your process is dying or is ended or something is wrong (exception or throw).

You can use [`erlang:monitor/2`](http://erlang.org/doc/man/erlang.html#monitor-2), this is similar to [`erlang:link/1`](http://erlang.org/doc/man/erlang.html#link-1) except the message go directly into process mailbox.

You can also hack Erlang, and use some internal way (shared `ETS`/`DETS`/`Mnesia` tables) or use external methods (database or other things like that). This is clearly not recommended and "destroy" Erlang philosophy... But you can do it.

Its seems your problem can be solved with [`supervisor`](http://erlang.org/doc/man/supervisor.html) behavior. `supervisor` support many [strategies](http://erlang.org/doc/design_principles/sup_princ.html#id78300) to control supervised process:

> - `one_for_one`: If one child process terminates and is to be restarted, only that child process is affected. This is the default restart strategy.
> - `one_for_all`:  If one child process terminates and is to be restarted, all other child processes are terminated and then all child processes are restarted.
> - `rest_for_one`: If one child process terminates and is to be restarted, the 'rest' of the child processes (that is, the child processes after the terminated child process in the start order) are terminated. Then the terminated child process and all child processes after it are restarted.
> - `simple_one_for_one`: A simplified one_for_one supervisor, where all child processes are dynamically added instances of the same process type, that is, running the same code.

You can also modify or create your own supervisor strategy from scratch or base on [`supervisor_bridge`](http://erlang.org/doc/man/supervisor_bridge.html).

So, to summarize, you need a process who wait for one or more terminating process. This behavior is supported natively with OTP, but you can also create your own model. For doing that, you need to share status of every started process, using cache or database, or when your process is spawned. Something like that:

```erlang
Fun = fun 
  MyFun (ParentProcess, {result, Data}) 
    when is_pid(ParentProcess) ->
      ParentProcess ! {self(), Data};
  MyFun (ParentProcess, MyData) 
    when is_pid(ParentProcess) ->
      % do something
      MyFun(ParentProcess, MyData2) end.

spawn(fun() -> Fun(self(), InitData) end).
```

**EDIT**: forgot to add an example without `send`/`receive`. I use an `ETS` table to store every result from lambda function. This `ETS` table is set when we spawn this process. To get result, we can select data from this table. Note, the key of the row is the process id of the process.

```erlang
spawner(Ets, Fun, Args) 
  when is_integer(Ets), 
       is_function(Fun) -> 
    spawn(fun() -> Fun(Ets, Args) end).

Fun = fun 
  F(Ets, {result, Data}) ->
    ets:insert(Ets, {self(), Data});
  F(Ets, Data) ->
    % do something here
    Data2 = Data,
    F(Ets, Data2) end.
```

Comment: I don't see how this is related to supervisors, and I don't it is supported natively by OTP.